# Why don't these back ticks format code in comment?

Tags: support, comments, code-formatting

Here is [the comment I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713609/how-to-split-text-in-ruby-without-creating-empty-strings/9713660#comment12359621_9713660), but the back ticks do not display as code. It works in this post. How to fix?

No, I got `=> ["this", "is", "the", "string", "to's", "split", "real", "", "ok", "", "nice-like"]` which has one empty string.

Comment: No, I got ``=> ["this", "is", "the", "string", "to's", "split", "real", "", "ok", "", "nice-like"]`` which has one empty string.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this *only* if there's a space between the backtick and =. Like this: ` = broken` ... Working: `= Working`

Comment: Though, everything with a space between the backtick and the first character of the code breaks...not sure if that's a bug.

Comment: No, I got => `No, I got => ["this", "is", "the", "string", "to's", "split", "real", "", "ok", "", "nice-like"]`

Comment: Wow, this is a really awful bug. In [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205567/how-to-execute-an-arbitrary-simple-command-over-ssh-without-knowing-the-login-sh?noredirect=1#comment891090_205567), a space after the backtick was necessary to explain the code.

Comment: Look at this example: I'm going to write `<backtick><space><...some text...><backtick><dot>`. The `<dot>` will function as ”end of sentence“. After that, I'm going to write `<backtick><...some more text...><backtick><dot>`; this time **there's no space**. In the demo you will see that _the text between the two code sections_ **(!)** will be monospace. — **Here's the demo:** ` ...some text...`. Here comes the second code section: `...some more text...`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must not have blank space after the first backtick or before the last backtick.

In your comment to that answer you do have space before the last backtick:

[image: comment space]

Apparently the code filter in the comments is different and more "strict" than the filter in the posts but this explains this issue.

Whether by design or a bug, only developer can tell. :)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I think it's a bug because the functionality is different when posting a question and posting an comment. Also, I don't see any reason that a space should prevent it from formatting code.

Comment: I agree so you can leave it tagged as a bug and hopefully mod or dev will come along and post official answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you *do want* a space as the first or last character in between the backticks, there's a (quite ugly) **workaround**:

Write

```
<backtick><U+2060><space>...some code...<backtick>
```

or

```
<backtick>...some code...<space><U+2060><backtick>
```

Note the `U+2060`, which is the Unicode [**word joiner** (WJ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_joiner). It's **zero width** (hence invisible) and **non-breaking**. You can copy-paste it from here:

```
«⁠»
```

It's enclosed in between `«` and `»`. You may need to select/copy the whole line (all three characters) to catch it, and then remove the enclosing characters after pasting.

**Warning:** there is a chance that when someone copies the code (`⁠ ...some code... ⁠`) *including* the invisible word joiner and pastes that into a code editor or a terminal, something won't work and, since the WJ is invisible, it's not obvious why it doesn't work. (I don't know if there's a solution to this..)

Comment: **demo:** `⁠ ...some code...`, `...some code... ⁠`